# ¿Cómo puedo visualizar una tabla con arrays dentro del objetos?

Tags: html, nodejs, vue.js, vuetify

Tengo este objeto en json:

```
{
  "transporte": "Vehiculo",
  "color": "Negro",
  "placas": 123,
  "Movimientos": [
    {
        "ruta": "Mexico",
        "estadia": "2 dias"
    },
    {
        "ruta":"Campeche",
        "estadia":"3 dias"
    }
  ],
  "estado": 1
}
```

Como puedo mostrar el objeto en forma de tabla de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera de mostrar la tabla de esta manera ya sea usando bootstrap o vuetify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho una aproximación a lo que pides, usando vanilla javascript y algo de bootstrap (pero solo para hacerlo más bonito). En el propio codigo he puesto lo que hace. Lo que no entiendas pregunta.

```js
// Datos de partida
var arr = [{
  "transporte": "Vehiculo",
  "color": "Negro",
  "placas": 123,
  "Movimientos": [{
      "ruta": "Mexico",
      "estadia": "2 dias"
    },
    {
      "ruta": "Campeche",
      "estadia": "3 dias"
    }
  ],
  "estado": 1
}];

// inicializamos la salida
html = '';

// recorremos los datos
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  // asignamos a variable 
  var obj = arr[i];

  // recorremos los movimientos de cada vehiculo
  for (var j = 0; j < obj['Movimientos'].length; j++) {
    var movimientos = obj['Movimientos'][j];

    // agregamos fila a la salida
    var html = html + '<tr><td>' + obj['transporte'] + '</td><td>' + obj['color'] + '</td><td>' + obj['placas'] + '</td><td>' + movimientos['ruta'] + '</td><td>' + movimientos['estadia'] + '</td></tr>';
  }
}

// asignamos a variable el id del DOM donde insertar el resultado
var elem = document.querySelector('#eltbody');

// modificamos el DOM con la salida generada
elem.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="salida">
    <thead class="table-light">
      <th>Transporte</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Placas</th>
      <th>Rutas</th>
      <th>Estadia</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="eltbody"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Estás haciendo muy buenos aportes a la comunidad, aún así, fijate que el OP (autor de la pregunta) hizo una pregunta amplia y no mostró lo que intentó hasta el momento (básicamente está haciendo lo que en inglés se conoce como _gimme the codez_ o su equivalente _denme el código_, asumiendo así que [es.so] es un servicio de código). Recordá que es mejor responder a preguntas [bien formadas](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @padaleiana: Gracias por la aclaración y entiendo perfectamente lo que dices. Cuando les doy el código de esta forma es porque a su vez he aprendido ha hacerlo yo mismo (mi nivel de javascript antes de empezar a responder aquí era cero patatero), y asi la comunidad tambien puede corregirme a mi tambien y aprender de ello. Soy un egoista, porque ademas solo lo hago en casos faciles donde entiendo lo que piden a pesar que no se hayan preocupado demasiado en codificarlo minimamente :-)  Y tambien para que no huyan cuando les decimos lo del [ask] y todos esos enlaces que a segun quien les abruma.

Comment: @padeleiana: Tambien piensa que soy relativamente nuevo aqui posteando respuestas, aunque ya hace alguna semana más que me inicié en el SO en ingles y alli veo que enseguida cierran preguntas de este estilo, pero aquí noto una cierta dejadez en ello, y veo las preguntas abiertas "in eternum" y si me interesa pues decido contestar como he explicado antes.  Si las terminan cerrando pues nada, yo ya me he divertido y de paso he ayudado a alguien que quizas no sepa preguntar pero necesita un cable potente o terminar una tarea de cole pronto.